# facebook's sharing debugger gives response code 0

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have the following problem: when I'm trying to check how facebook shares my website, I get the following errors:

*Inferred Property:* The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

*Missing Properties:* The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id

*Could Not Connect To Server:* Check that the webserver is running, and that there are no firewalls blocking Facebook's crawlers.

*Curl Error:* Curl error: 56 (RECV_ERROR)

The response code is 0.

Anyone an idea?

EDIT: it was a problem with my DNS-settings. It works now.

Comment: What was the problem with DNS

Comment: I got the same problem, can you please tell me what did you do with the DNS?

Comment: I reconnected the DNS to the website, that was the problem.